# Group texts next each other

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I open a PDF on Illustrator, somethings the text layers are separated -- possiblely because of PDF compression. How I can group this text layers in a unique layer -- not grouping.

Example:

```
Many text layers:  [H][ello ][Wor][ld][!]
Unique text layer: [Hello World!]
```

[image: Image1]

I colored each text node just for explain (you can note nodes too because of blue dots), naturally it is a unique color. I need that it turns in a unique text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There IS an automated method. You can use Wundes' [Join text frames](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) script, which will take all the separate text boxes and merge them into one.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text with the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow).

**Copy and delete** or use `Edit > Cut`

Grab the **Text Tool** and click to start a new text object, then just **paste**. The formatting (color) should paste right along with the text.

The pasted text will be one string. You may have to reposition the new text string.

One way to get around repositioning is to copy everything, then delete everything *except* the first text object. Then using the Text Tool, highlight that remaining text, then paste.

Comment: I need do it manually over all project? Because are 30 pages, but the text is not plain. Basically are "tags" that defines some images aspects. So I need do it about 1.000 (literally).

Comment: There's no automated method I'm aware of. This is generally why it's best to work from the Illustrator file if possible, rather than a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but I just found a workaround for grouping text together. You can create a random shape and then select all of the text and the shape you just created. Then you can group the items together. After grouping them, you can just delete the shape and the text stays grouped together.